# Выдает ошибку php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqli, php7

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Выдает: что "Регистрация не удалась" и на базу данных ничего не приходит, в чем мб ошибка?

```css
/* Файл connect.php, просто не знаю, как правильно тут сделать*/
<?php 
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'pratice');
$select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'pratice'); // Выбираем базу данных

?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Registers</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php
require('connect.php');

if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) // isset - Определяет, была ли установлена переменная, 
{
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $emal = $_POST['email'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];

 $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password')";// Добавляем в mysql значения
 $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query); // Для подключения к базе данных

 if($result) // Теперь проверяем прошла ли регистрация или нет
 {
  $smsg = "Регистрация прошла успешно";
 } else {
  $fsmsg = "Регистрация не удалась";
 }
}
?>


 <div class="container">
  <form class="form-signin" method="POST">
   <h3>Registration</h3>
   
   <?php if(isset($smsg)){ ?> <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><?php echo $smsg; ?></div><?php }?>
   <?php if(isset($fsmsg)){ ?> <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><?php echo $fsmsg; ?></div><?php }?>

   <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required> <!-- required - значит обязательно для ввода -->
   <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
   <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
   <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">REGISTER</button><!-- btn, чтобы определить кнопку; btn-lg, размер кнопки; btn-primary, цвет кнопки; btn-block, размещение кнопки -->


  </form>
 
 </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$fsmsg = "Регистрация не удалась<br>\r\n".mysqli_error ($connection);`
Попробуйте так, и вам станет всё понятно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в этой строке кода.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password')";// Добавляем в mysql значения
```

Она не совпадает со структурой БД.
Замените этой строкой и всё заработает:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email,active) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password',0)";// Добавляем в mysql значения
```

Немного пояснений:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итого ваш запрос обязательно должен установить поле active, т.к. оно не может быть без значения(Null) и для него нет значения "по умолчанию".

Можно так же установить для данного поля(в БД) или значение по умолчанию(например 0) или возможность установки в Null и тогда код на php можно не менять.

Comment: Спасибо большое, все заработало!)

Comment: Помогло - ставьте галочку у ответа =)

Answer (score -2):

1. В файле подключеня к бд не нужно указывать

   $select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'pratice');

т.к ты уже указал базу данных в переменной $connection.
2. Сделай вот так:

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);

$emal = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

$password = md5($_POST['password']); // Или можешь использовать другой метод шифрования
```

3. Пробуй так

   ```
   if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){

   $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES('$username','$email', '$password')";
   $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

   echo = "Регистрация прошла успешно";
   } else {
   echo = "Пользователь не найден";
   }
   ```

Как-то так , у меня все заработало так!

Comment: Советы отчасти правильные, кроме третьего, он в корне неверен и даже вреден в том виде в котором он здесь написан. Так что минус,ибо к ответу это не имеет отношения, максимум комментарий и то только первый и второй пункт.

Comment: И да, ваш код у автора вопроса не заработает =)